# Why this code not work in external C# Classes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#

When I use This code in external C# Classes doesn't work

but it works great of course for aspx and their code-behind pages.

`Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'open' takes '3' arguments`

```
public  static string SMSSEND(string username, string password, string too, string text, string FromNumber)
{
    string sMsg = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(text);
    string sBaseUrl = "Http://www.payam-resan.com/APISend.aspx";

    HttpContext.Current.Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");

    MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP objHTTP = new MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTPClass();

    objHTTP.open("POST", sBaseUrl, false);
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    objHTTP.send("Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password + "&From=" + FromNumber + "&To=" + too + "&Text=" + sMsg);

    return objHTTP.responseText;
}
```

my class

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class SMS_P : System.Web.UI.Page
    {       
        public  static string SMSSEND(string username, string password, string too, string text, string FromNumber)
        {
            string sMsg = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(text);
            string sBaseUrl = "Http://www.payam-resan.com/APISend.aspx";

            HttpContext.Current.Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");

            MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP objHTTP = new MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTPClass();

            objHTTP.open("POST", sBaseUrl, false);
            objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            objHTTP.send("Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password + "&From=" + FromNumber + "&To=" + too + "&Text=" + sMsg);

            return objHTTP.responseText;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post external c# class code?

Comment: i add class and just use  The above code!@Freesiah

Comment: I would like to see your class code to find out the problem.

Comment: @Freesiah plz check it tnx

Comment: You must call your SMSSEND method like SMS_P sms_p = new SMS_P(); sms_p.SMSSEND("username", "pwd", "to","text","fromnumber"); Are you calling your SMSSEND method like this? or at least you must call this method in page load or click events or any other methods. Just placing a method inside a class does not work.

Comment: @Freesiah  when i use this code in pages of  asp not problem !but i use this code in class .When I run the project ،I am faced with the following problem in Compile :No overload for method 'open' takes '3' arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you check your External class codes which you call the method 'open' you will see that you are trying to call the XMLHHTP.Open() method with just 3 parameters. The method

```
objHTTP.open("POST", sBaseUrl, false);
```

has 3 parameters.

So the parameters should be like;

```
oServerXMLHTTPRequest.open(bstrMethod, bstrUrl, bAsync, bstrUser, bstrPassword);
```

Explained in the following link to MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763809(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My problem is that this code does not work just in class